# É possível alterar CSS de um iframe?

Tags: css, google-api, google-calendar

Tenho o seguinte `iframe` do Google Calendar incorporado:

```
<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?showNav=0&amp;showPrint=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;showTz=0&amp;height=600&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23ffffff&amp;src=exemplo.com;color=%23182C57&amp;ctz=America%2FSao_Paulo" style="border-width:0;" width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Estou puxando esse `iframe` de uma agenda do Google, a pergunta é: Consigo alterar o `CSS` desse `iframe`?

Preciso alterar cores, fontes, etc. Gostaria de saber se existe alguma possibilidade de fazer isso, ou se alguém conhece outra forma de fazer essas edições no Google Calendar.

Comment: Você quer alterar o interior do `iframe`?

Comment: Cara, por padrão já posso te dizer que não vai conseguir manipular a página "de baixo", nem com css nem com js nem com nada. Isso por motivos de segurança nós somos impedidos. Mas já procurou na documentação do google a respeito?

Comment: @I_like_trains sim...

Comment: Com PHP vc consegue resolver isso. Veja esse artigo com a sua resposta https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/04/integrating-google-calendar-with-your-website/

Comment: @hugocsl já segui os passos desse tutorial, mas parece que o mesmo está desatualizado.

Comment: Vixi, então complicou rss... Vc pode tentar baixar os arquivos pela aba Source do Dev Tools do Chrome e chama-los direto do seu arquivo local na página para ver se funciona. Nunca tentei isso, mas vai que resolve...

Comment: Não da certo :(

Comment: Confere http://sugi.github.io/jquery-gcal-flow/

Answer (score 1):

Até onde eu saiba, somente tendo acesso ao DOM usando js ex:

```
var estilo = document.createElement('link');
estilo.rel = 'stylesheet';
estilo.type = 'text/css';
estilo.href = 'caminho/estilo.css';
seuIframe.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(estilo);
```